# Check-In/Map API

Tags: php, javascript, ios, ruby, api

I'm trying to get some information for a application we would like to develop for our business. We run a chain of stores (approximately 20) and would like to give our customers reward points when they check-in to our store location. We would also like to display that information our company site eg. "Client X has checked in Location Y". I was wondering if anyone can point me to any API(s) or solutions that may be able to achieve something along these lines? I was looking at the foursquare API, is this a viable option? or is there any other recommendations?

Thank you

Comment: FourSquare is the right place to achieve what you want. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

As Fahri pointed you can use 4sq API, but nowadays all socials integrate geolocation. You can share your position also using Facebook and Twitter. I will suggest to use the last two, because they has integrated authentication, and API since iOS6, probably they are also more used than 4SQ.